# How to sent (fetch) data from js to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, post, fetch-api

I want to make a register function

I try to do like this:

```
function finish() {

    if (valid) {
        const postData = {
          email: email.value,
          username: username.value,
          password: password.value,
          password2: password2.value
        };
      
        fetch('/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "aplication/json"
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(postData)
          });
    }
}
```

and in node js i have this:

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const newuser = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const repetpasword = req.body.password2;
    console.log(newuser);
    if (checkvalidinput(email, newuser, password, repetpasword)) {
      res.render('startpage')
    } else {
      const message = 'sumphing is wrong'
      res.render('errormessage' , {message: message});
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

});
```

when i try to display in console the variable "newuser" is dispaly "undefined", how can i solve that?
Any other idea, other metod forsent data from js to node.js?

Comment: email, password and password2 are OK? Did you check in the browser what it is sending? (in the network tab of the browser *developer* console) perhaps `username.value` is undefined?

Comment: Are you taking this value from a form then post the form HTML code as well. Let us see what you doing

Comment: You might need to install 'body-parser'.

Comment: `"Content-type": "aplication/json"` also typo here, aPPlication

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the fetch and node parts.

- In the fetch function on js
  be sure you send the correct data (username)
- If the fetch sends the username data correctly, then see the node.
  Should be json part from the request.

  const data = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const email = data.email;
  const newuser = data.username;
  const password = data.password;
  const repetpasword = data.password2;
  console.log(newuser);
  It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [creds, setcreds] = useState({
        email:"",
        newuser:"",
        password:"",
        repetpasword :""
    })

const handleChange=(e)=>{
        setcreds({...creds,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }

function finish() {
       if(valid){const postData=creds}

        fetch('/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "aplication/json"
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(postData)
          });
    }
}
```

Give the names (email,newuser,password,repetpasword ) i,e name='email' to respective input tags and add the onChange={handleChange} in all the input tags.

Check by adding a console.log and you are good to go.